# how to deploy a stack in multiple regions using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

How to deploy a stack in multiple regions using the Serverless Framework?

For example, I need to deploy a stack of API Gateway, DynamoDB, Elasticsearch and lambda resources in 6 regions

I found a solution for regional deployment using pure CloudFormation and StackSet, but how can I do this using the Serverless Framework? this is the only solution I have found https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy#deployment-with-stage-and-region-options

Answer (score 1):

There's a Serverless [Plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-multi-region-plugin) which does this, but you'll get 6 different stacks with 6 independent functions, dynamo tables, ES Clusters, etc.

If that's what you want, the plugin should work. If you need to synchronize data (from Dynamo or ElasticSearch) across all regions, you'll need a different approach (Global Tables, etc).